# How do I use Go for backend for svelte MPA?

Tags: go, svelte

I would like to use go for the webserver for my svelte application that has multiple html pages.
I would prefer it if I could use a file system based router but any would be fine.
I also need this to work with some kind of development server that has hot reload.

I hope I am understanding all this and its terminology correctly (I'm not very experienced with this kind of thing) so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out these two articles:

[Creating a website using Golang and Svelte](https://dev.to/ksckaan1/creating-a-website-using-golang-and-sveltejs-together-55g8)

[Combine Go (golang) and SvelteKit for GUI](https://codeandlife.com/2022/02/12/combine-golang-and-sveltekit-for-gui/)

I am currently using Go for my API and then a seperate client in svelte (sveltekit) that makes fetch calls to the Go API. Although this isn't exactly provided in those articles, I believe they will provide some solid context.

Comment: Thanks the second link seems to work well but I have also found this for anyone else trying to do this which could be useful: https://blog.logrocket.com/full-stack-bud-go/

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/kokizzu/svelte-mpa

It changes default Svelte behavior from component to page, all component should start with underscore.

I built this exactly for MPA use-case.